# Outlook Addin: Serialization & Stream Issue

Tags: c#, serialization, vsto, outlook-addin

I've been working on an outlook-addin that tracks specific emails in a treeview control. When opening and closing outlook the treenodes are serialized/deserialized and saved to a file via a stream. The issue I'm having is when I close the application after adding new TreeNodes it doesn't always serialize and save. This seems to only happen when I quickly open the application, add some nodes and close. When I don't open and close in a short period of time it works just fine.

My code is below and I think is pretty straight forward. I'm relatively inexperienced and I'm thinking there must be some fundamental rule I'm not following here. My guess is I'm not properly using the stream class??

```
((Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_Event)Application).Quit += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_QuitEventHandler(ThisAddIn_Quit);

private void PopulateTree()
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream fileO = File.Open(@"Data.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                if (fileO.Length != 0)
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    object obj = bf.Deserialize(fileO);

                    TreeNode[] nodeList = (obj as IEnumerable<TreeNode>).ToArray();

                    Globals.ThisAddIn.myUserControl1.ResponseTree.Nodes.AddRange(nodeList);   
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    void ThisAddIn_Quit()
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream file = File.Open(@"Data.dat", FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(file, Globals.ThisAddIn.myUserControl1.ResponseTree.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the Quit event called every time? Did you try to debug the code? See [Shutdown Changes for Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee720183(v=office.14).aspx#OL2010AdditionalShutdownChanges_AddinShutdownChangesinOL2010Beta) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it confirmed that I'm subscribing to the correct event. It's very bizarre, I only have issues when I'm repeatedly debugging my code. I'm positive the event is called each time I exit. The only thing I can thing is the treeview object disappears from memory before it can serialize so nothing is saved?? I guess the solution might be to serialize & save every time the treeview is altered.

Comment: Yep. Try to implement that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Tristan,

The [Shutdown Changes for Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee720183(v=office.14).aspx#OL2010AdditionalShutdownChanges_AddinShutdownChangesinOL2010Beta) article has the following text:

*Be sure that you respond quickly to the event and return control to Outlook as quickly as possible. Your add-ins should create no delay in Outlook shutdown that is perceptible to the user. Compare the time it takes for Outlook to shut down with only your add-in running, and the time it takes for Outlook to shut down without any add-ins running to identify any significant difference.*

*Explicitly, do not perform network I/O operations during any quit event. This includes saving data to a network share, writing data to an Outlook online-mode store, or calling Web services during Application.Quit, OnBeginShutdown, or OnDisconnection.*

It seems you need to choose another place for serializing the tree data.

Comment: The article doesn't say you can't use the quit event just to avoid it because it can delay the shutdown particularly when you are performing network I/O operations. Either way I tried dumping the code to save the file into a button click method and it will save a few times but after a few repeated saves it stops saving all together. There must be an issue with how I'm implementing the stream??